# MySQL get calculated column and all column(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table and i have columns. I want to get AGE column- it is creating (current date - year column data)- and whole columns like *.

I tried;

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(dateOfBirth)) as age , * FROM users
```

but it gives error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM users LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

What should i write? Thank you!

Comment: Pls show full your query and the name of column `dateOfBirth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified tbl_name.* reference' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

This is ok

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(dateOfBirth)) as age, users.* FROM users
```

Answer (score 2):

use alias and `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function

```
SELECT u.*,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dateOfBirth, CURRENT_DATE) as age
FROM users u
```